# Размерность в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Вопрос: перемещение в Unity на 1 по оси x, то есть допустим с координаты (0;0) перемещение в координату (1;0), это перемещение на сколько пикселей? И можно ли это перемещение регулировать? То есть делать больше или меньше по пикселям? Или вопрос некорректен и это расстояние никак в пикселях не измерить?

Comment: В ортографическом режиме зависит от настроек камеры и разрешения рендера.

Comment: Пиксели и условные единицы измерения (units в unity) - это две абсолютно разных величины, не особо зависимых друг от друга, по крайней мере в стандартном понимании. Пиксели на экране - это *проекция* объектов. Можно, конечно, рассчитать параметры положения камеры относительно объекта, чтобы 1 пиксель относился к 1 unit'у как 1:1 или какое вам там значение нужно (вам нужно понимать, что двигающийся объект должен двигаться параллельно плоскости камеры). Однако вы 99% делаете что-то не так, особенно если речь идет про какие-то 2д игры.

Answer (score 0):

Можно преобразовать систему координат пикселей в Мировую систему координат.
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(transform.position);

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] Camera _camera = default;
    [SerializeField] CanvasScaler _canvasScaler = default;

    void Start() {
        Debug.Log($"1 пикслель равен {GetPixelInUnits()} юнитов");
    }

    public float GetPixelInUnits() {
        return _camera.orthographicSize * 2 / _canvasScaler.referenceResolution.y;
    }
}
```