# Как получить размер игрового поля не в пикселях а размере игровой сетки | Unity2D

Tags: unity3d, объекты, координаты

Неделю изучаю Unity, все шло хорошо до одного момента. Хотел сделать условие, что если игрок перешел за определенную линию по координате X то, он дальше не может идти. И тут начались проблемы с проверкой!

1. При получении координат объекта созданного через 2D Object/Sprites/Circle выдаются координаты, по игровой сетке то-есть, X=2.1, Y=5.8 и т.д.
2. При получении размеров окна Canvas, я получаю размеры в пикселях, а мне надо также, как и в пункте 1 получить размер не в пикселях, а по сетке.

Если найдется ответ то, хочу сразу задать еще один вопрос! Как лучше работать, с сеткой или в пикселях?

Comment: У вас игрок на канвасе?!

Comment: Нет, Canvas у меня для кнопок, текста и т.д.

Comment: Так, зачем вам тогда канвас?

Comment: Точнее зачем вы вообще упомянули про канвас?

Comment: Хорошо, а если не использовать canvas, то как получить размер игрового поля не в пикселях?

Comment: Какое Поле?! Составьте чёткый вопрос, в котором описываете что и где расположено

Comment: Мне надо получить размер экрана, не в пикселях, а в ячейках по X и Y

Comment: Вот это случайно не ваш вопрос с другого аккаунта: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1293826/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-unity? Просто так похожи!

Comment: `а мне надо также, как и в пункте 1 получить размер не в пикселях, а по сетке.` - зачем вам это надо? Может вы просто применяете неверный подход к решению более общей задачи?

Comment: Да, вопрос тот же

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на свой же вопрос!
Узнал про системы координат в Unity, есть Мировые и Экранные. Мировые координаты - это как раз и есть та сетка о которой я говорил, а Экранные координаты указываются в пикселях.

Для преобразования Экранной системы координат в Мировую можно использовать Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(transform.position);

Не судите за мои неконструктивные вопросы, так как изучаю Unity и C# только неделю. Всем удачи.